# rsync out of git repository or tar archive

Tags: git, tar, rsync

I have a git repository and I want to rsync a particular revision of the repository into a directory. Basically I want to do this:

```
$ cd my-git-repo
$ git archive $MY_COMMIT > ~/blah.tar.gz
$ mkdir ~/tmp
$ cd ~/tmp
$ tar xf ~/blah.tar.gz
$ rsync -a ~/tmp/ ~/final-destination
$ cd
$ rm -r tmp
```

The problem with this is it requires extracting to a temporary directory and rsyncing from that. This is (theoretically) unnecessary and with a huge git repository takes a long time and requires a lot of free space. I don't just want to clear ~/final-destination and tar directly into it with:

```
$ git archive $MY_COMMIT | tar x -C ~/final-destination
```

because this also requires a lot of unnecessary work especially if ~/final-destination is a remote directory. Another option would be to checkout the particular revision and rsync directly out of the repository:

```
$ git checkout $MY_COMMIT
$ rsync -a --exclude .git my-git-repo/ ~/final-destination
```

but I'd rather not mess with the repository's working directory. I want to do all this in a script that may run in the background while I'm doing stuff in the respository.

So. Is there a way to rsync directly out of a particular revision of a repository. Or failing that can I somehow rsync from the tar archive without having to extract it?

Comment: have you tried `git push/pull` or `git format-patch/am` (the remote end should be a git repo too in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

<del>If you don't want to `rsync` out of your working tree, I'm afraid that you're stuck with extracting to a temporary directory first.  (Although when I say that kind of thing on Stack Overflow, inevitably someone comes up with something more ingenious :))</del>

One thing you could try is to stash your changes, checkout the commit you want, rsync, switch back to the previous branch then pop the stash again:

```
set -e

git stash
git checkout $MY_COMMIT
rsync -a --exclude .git ./ ~/final-destination
git checkout -
git stash pop
```

(I haven't tested that, I should warn you.)